# Trying to find the ODE for $(1+ \frac{x}{n})^n, n\neq0$ family?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the ODE for this family $$\left(1+ \frac{x}{n}\right)^n, n\neq0$$ but I can´t complete it. I understand that as the equation has only one parameter then the ODE will be a first order ODE.

I have:

$y = \left(1+ \dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n$

$y' =\left(1+ \dfrac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}$

so,

$y=y' \left( 1 + \dfrac{x}{n} \right)$

But I can't remove $n$ in the last equation.

Comment: So $n=x/(y/y'-1)$. You can put that in your original equation.

Comment: Note that $$y=y'(1+x/n)\implies (\log (y))'=(1+x/n)^{-1}$$

Comment: $\frac y{y'}=1+\frac xn$ gives $\left(\frac y{y'}\right)''=0$

Comment: Hint: $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \approx e^x$.